# How to get my uv mesh to show?

Tags: mesh, uv

Okay so for a week now I've been trying to get this one area in blender to work so that I can finish making the outfit that I made in MD. I've watched tutorials over and over, doing every step that they say to do and I'll be darned if it still doesn't work for me. (pulling hair out) I've even remade different outfits, but when she joins hers with the s4studio_mesh_1 her uv map appears above the uv map that was edited. Mine on the other hand just disappears. Here are a couple of pictures to help show you what I mean.
[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps : https://blenderartists.org/t/picture-map-disappears-from-uv-editor/455538/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is present. Easy to miss, because all of it is at the origin: 0,0. (you can see an orange dot. That's all of your vertices stack on top of each other)

Why that is is a different issue. The most likely culprit is different UV slot names that are improperly merging.

That is, if you're certain that before the merge you did have UV data.

Comment: Yay! Thank you SOOOOOO much!!!